# Indexing (start, stop) a Python Array using String

Tags: python, arrays, indexing

I have a python string array. How do I index the stop and end of this array with string?
i.e. Is there a way I can get from "dad" to "dog", inclusive, by setting the start and stop of this array? I can assume that there are no repetitions, and the unique array is ordered as I want to.

`fam_arr = ['mom', 'dad', 'sister', 'brother', 'dog', 'cat']`

output:
`subset_arr = ['dad', 'sister', 'brother', 'dog']`

Comment: You can use slice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Comment: I don't think you can slice an array using string like such:
```fam_arr ['dad' : 'dog']```
I will get an error : slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Answer (score 1):

In this case use can use slice for example

```py
fam_arr = ['mom', 'dad', 'sister', 'brother', 'dog', 'cat']
print(fam_arr[1:5])
```

the result

```
['dad', 'sister', 'brother', 'dog']
```

but if you don't know where is the index of dad and dog you need to search the index of the list after that you can use slice